# Extracting Hidden HTML Elements in Visual Studio Web Performance and Load Test Projects

Tags: html, visual-studio, load-testing, web-performance

I am creating a load test script using Visual Studio but I'm unable to extract values from html elements like this:

[HTML Hidden Element Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MaSIV.png)

I would like to extract the value of the *value* attribute in the *input* tag so I can put randomizations on it.

I will appreciate any help. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to user an extraction rule.
After you recorded your navigation, right click on the url that you want to extract your value and choose "Add extraction rule" from the context menu.

This will open the following screen:

[image]

The you can choose what better fits your needs, for instance: extract hidden fields, extract a form field, use a regular expression to find what you are looking for.

In your case, based on the image you added to your question, maybe the Extract Regular Expression.

Comment: I tried using the extraction rules but I am not able to extract the data I want since it's "blurred" on Firebug. The Response HTML doesn't include it. Do you know any other way?